# Dynamic enabling and disabling of camel throttle

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to use camel throttle to delay message processing if my cxf endpoint is down, need suggestion as How to disable throttling once cxf is up and running back.

Answer (score 0):

If the cxf endpoint is down, throttling will still lead to errors-- just slower. I suggest 'stopping' the route instead, or breaking your route into two routes.. one to store messages in a queue and the other to read and send to the cxf endpoint.

The message queue acts like a natural buffer for traffic spikes, throttle and holding pen if the remote endpoint is down.

If you really must stick with the existing design using a throttle, then extract the throttle values in a config. During "down" periods set the throttle count to really high values. During "up" periods set the throttle time to 0ms and the throttle count to a really high value-- the throttle will effectively be disabled.